# Modify VBA code to change cell input separately for each row

Tags: excel, vba

I've been troubleshooting this for a while, and am stuck... I'd like this to run on a row-by-row basis, where columns F thru L are multiplied by the value in column D when a number is entered.  Any suggestions?  (I am not a good programmer, but really want this functionality in my spreadsheet!) Thank you!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rate As Double

    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D74:L200"))

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        for Each row In rng.Rows
            rate = row.Columns.Item(0).Value
            For Each cell In row.Cells
                cell.Value = cell.Value * rate
            Next cell
        Next row
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Wait, do you want the multiplication to happen when you change the value in column D, or when you enter a value in `F74:L200`?

Comment: I want the multiplication to happen when I enter a value in columns F thru L.

Comment: Ok, then see my answer as is.

Answer (score 1):

Just a side note, I'd use a different variable name than `row` as that can be pretty confusing.

Also add some error handling in case you enter non-numeric input in that range:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rate As Double

    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F74:L200"))

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo SafeExit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each rw In rng.Rows
            rate = Me.Cells(rw.Row, "D").Value

            For Each cell In rw.Cells
                cell.Value = cell.Value * rate
            Next
        Next
    End If

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```